# How can I make sure a variable already got its value (in a for cycle) - ionic native mobile app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I tried running the code below. On the console, I got an empty array. Is it because it's asyncronous?

```js
...

export class HomePage {
   coords= [];

fillArray() 
{
  for (let i in myArray) {
     this.coords.push(myArray[i]);
  }

  console.log(this.coords);
}
```

Comment: how do you call fillArray and what is inside myArray?

Comment: To iterate over array items, use `for of` instead of `for in` (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)).

Comment: Or do it without a `for` loop: `this.coords.push(...myArray)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no asynchronous part involved, With ES6 if you want to directly push an array with spread syntax as follows.

```
fillArray() 
{
  this.coords.push(...myArray);
  console.log(this.coords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work ok, see simple test in app.component.ts here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4ti43?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). (Use the 'Open in new window' button to run).

`let i in myArray` is fine because the `in` syntax sets i to the index, and you are using it as such. As mentioned, you can also use the `of` syntax as below, but what you have is also good.

```js
for (let value of myArray) {
  this.coords.push(value);
}
```

Can you reproduce the error on a fork of the stackblitz?